# Jquery formvalidation required field if value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I currently have jquery form validation plugged in to my page, I currently have an issue trying to validate the state dropdown, how the view is built is like this. User chooses country which then fires back to controller and returns states linked to that country and builds the states dropdown. before choosing a country the state dropdown has a selected value of 0 and the text for that is "Please choose a state" from my understanding Jquery form validation will see that 0 and assume its a value, instead in my case this is not a value i need the user to choose a greater value of 0. so when the user presses submit, if the states selected value is 0 I need to display error message otherwise carry on. This is currently what I have

```
 $('#myForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        "UserDetails.SelectedCountry": "required",
        "UserDetails.SelectedState": {
            required: function (element) {
                var value = $("#UserDetails_SelectedState").val() == 0;

                if (value) { // If the value is true I need to return false to make it required
                    alert("here");
                    return false;
                } else { // Otherwise value is greater then 0 ok to carry on,
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
        "UserDetails.Postcode": "required"
    },
    messages: {
        "UserDetails.SelectedCountry": "Please choose your country",
        "UserDetails.SelectedState": "Please choose your state",
        "UserDetails.Postcode": "Please enter your postcode",
    }
});
```

Would someone please be able to tell/show how to validate against 0.

** Update **

I've been battling with this on and off today, as you can see from my jquery markup if it true I then return false I see the alert message "here" but the field does not highlight in red, nor is the error message "Please choose your state" shown, can someone thing of the top of there head what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

You may put the "Please choose a state" value to ="" and disabled it.

Something like this

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled>Please Choose a State</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Change you validation to this:

```
 var value = $("#UserDetails_SelectedState").val()
  if (value ==0 || value=="0") { // If the value is true I need to return false to make it required
                    alert("here");
                    return false;
                } else { // Otherwise value is greater then 0 ok to carry on,
                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: I would but its built from the database and i do not have access to the database.

Comment: Sorry, i can't get you? Can explain in more detail?

Comment: the dropdown is database drive, so how the code currently works is when the page is requested it fires a call to the database which takes a parameters, if parameters is null then it returns no states, so that's why I have 0 as a selected value, pretty stupid if you ask me the way its built this way but I can't change that I just need to add validation to it.

Comment: try to change your validation code? see my updated post

Comment: I see the alert here but the message "Please choose your State" is not shown

Comment: Anyone able to help with this?